# SharePoint 2013 development machine

Tags: 2013

i am looking through to get a desktop computer to start learning development and configuration on sharepoint 2013, i deceideed to get this computer,

> 1 x Intel Core i5-3570K 3.40GHz (Ivybridge) Socket LGA1155 Processor
>   (77W) - Retail £185.99
>
> 1 x Iiyama Prolite E2382HSD 23" Widescreen LED Monitor - Black
>   £119.99
>
> 1 x Kingston 120GB SSDNow V+200 Drive SATA 6Gb/s 3 2.5" (7mm height)
>   Solid State Hard Drive w/ Adapter - (SVP200S37A/120G) £95.99
>
> 1 x GeIL Black Dragon 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3 PC3-12800C11 1600MHz Dual
>   Channel Kit (GD316GB1600C11DC) **OcUK Exclusive** £95.99
>
> 1 x MSI HD 7770 GHz Edition 1024MB GDDR5 PCI-Express Graphics Card
>   £89.99
>
> 1 x Asus P8Z77-V LX Intel Z77 (Socket 1155) DDR3 Motherboard £85.99
>
> 1 x XFX Pro 650W Core Edition '80 Plus Bronze' Power Supply £64.99
>
> 1 x Seagate Barracuda 7200RPM 1TB SATA 6Gb/s 64MB Cache - OEM
>   (ST1000DM003) HDD £53.99
>
> 1 x BitFenix Shinobi USB3.0 Gaming Case - Black £49.99
>
> 1 x Samsung SH-118AB/BEBE SATA 18x DVD-ROM (Black) - OEM £12.95 Total
>   : £872.35 (includes shipping : £13.75).

I find it here    http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/showthread.php?p=24600710#post24600710

I will have 3 tier topology and virtualized server;s on top of windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off with a single server for SharePoint when developing with Visual Studio.  However, for testing deployments, a multi-server installation is an important test case and validation of your solution.

You're going to likely want 32+GB RAM for your multi-server installation, allocating between 10 - 16GB/SharePoint server.  You'll also need a Domain Controller, and of course your SQL Server, plus any other services you might want to test (AD RMS, Certificate Services, Exchange).

Comment: Totally agree, my dev server has 32GB of RAM and I can barely run a multi server environment with Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 will require a minimum of 12 GB to run without problems, so a 16GB laptop is quite short.

I tried to run SP15 on a VM with 8GB of RAM and ran into lots of **Out of Memory** issues. Things get worse when you need to open Visual Studio, SharePoint Designer and a few other things all at the same time.

If you provision a Search Service Application it will create a minimum of 5 aditional processes in your server (may create more depending on your search topology) and these will take some more memory. Provision a few more Service Applications and Web Applications and you'll see all your RAM go away.

My development server now runs on 16GB of RAM and is working just fine.